# jquery loading after script that is included below it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where I have something like this at the end of the page:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="onload-test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my network tab it shows everything being loaded using `h2` (http/2) and `onload-test.js` is **loaded before** `jquery.js` causing an error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

as I am using `$(document).ready()` in my script. The network tab shows **jquery.js being queued for ~200m**s.

Under what circumstances can this happen? and how can it be prevented?

Comment: Why don't you add the jQuery in `<head></head>` , is there any specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

use asycn while loading

```
<script async src="jquery.js"></script>
<script async src="onload-test.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to guarantee jQuery will load before my script.

Answer (score 0):

You can add jquery reference inside `"<head></head>"` section for best practice.
Body must contain only body specific js references.
jquery is a kind of global library which should be loaded in the `<head></head>` section.

You can refer: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide